# Split columns that are dictionaries

Tags: r, dictionary, split

I have a data frame that has about 200,000 rows with columns like:

| ID | dictionary column 1 | dictionary column 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {""1720100"":4,""1720101"":3} | {""1720100"":5,""1720101"":1,""1720102"":2} |
| 2 | {""1720100"":4} | {""1720100"":4,""1720101"":2} |
| ... | ... | ... |

The output table I would like to get is:

| ID | col_a | col_b | col_c | col_d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1720100 | 4 | 1720101 | 5 |
| 1 | 1720101 | 3 | 1720102 | 1 |
| 1 | NA | NA | 1720103 | 2 |
| 2 | 1720100 | 4 | 1720101 | 4 |
| 2 | NA | NA | 1720102 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

And, I feel like it would be even better if the data frame is divided into several chunks before splitting the columns above to reduce the time needed for the calculation. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may want to extract json from the column, using `jsonlite` package. You can put data into longer form, since you have json in two columns. Then with more pivoting to get desired final format. The final `select` just reorders columns values on the number contained in the column name.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>%
  mutate(json_parsed = map(value, ~fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]", .), flatten = T))) %>%
  unnest(json_parsed) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(ID, name, value), names_to = "n", values_to = "v") %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, values_from = c(n, v), values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest(cols = -ID) %>%
  select(ID, order(parse_number(names(.)[-1])) + 1)
```

**Output**

```
     ID n_dictionary_column_1 v_dictionary_column_1 n_dictionary_column_2 v_dictionary_column_2
  <dbl> <chr>                                 <int> <chr>                                 <int>
1     1 1720100                                   4 1720100                                   5
2     1 1720101                                   3 1720101                                   1
3     1 1720102                                  NA 1720102                                   2
4     2 1720100                                   4 1720100                                   4
5     2 1720101                                  NA 1720101                                   2
6     2 1720102                                  NA 1720102                                  NA
```